# What is the technique to achieve this effect?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to get similar effect (Snapshot) via html and css but could get the result ? I could assume that this one is done by css3 transition.

Anyone help me that how can i get this effect through css3 transition ?

[image] 
This is the site url

https://www.mrd.com/

I have tried with these

```
// HTML
 <span class="highlighter"></span>


// CSS

.highlighter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  transform: pulse 1s infinite;
  display: block;
}



.highlighter:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [CSS3 animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations). The site is using SVGs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.highlighter {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  transform: pulse 1s infinite;
  display: block;
  background:orange;
  -webkit-animation: big 2s infinite;
}



.highlighter:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -webkit-animation: big 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes big{
  50%{-webkit-transform:scale(1.3,1.3);}
  100%{transform:scale(1,1):}
  }
```

```html
<span class="highlighter"></span>
```